# Complicated test to check which object instantiates a function call

Tags: c++

I have a struct ( can be class ) and is defined in another class as shown

```
struct A{
somedata_A;
somespecificimplementation_A(someclass *S1);
};

class someclass{
somedata_someclass;
A a;
};

main(){
 someclass c1, *c2;
 c2 = &c1;
 c1.a.somespecificimplementation_A(c2);
}
```

How do I verify that c2 is indeed a reference for c1? Pardon me for putting up this example as it is obvious that c2 is reference for c1.

*Update*: A does not store a pointer to someclass

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? `c2` points to `c1` if `&c1 == c2`. Is that what you're asking? Or do you want to know whether `c1` actually still exists just by looking at `c2`?

Comment: @NikosC. I want to know whether &c1 == c2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't know nothing about parent, compare member' adresses

```
void A::somespecificimplementation_A(someclass *S1)
{
    if (this == &(S1->a)) {
        // parent == S1
    } else {
        // parent != S1
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea.  Much simpler than my solution.  (Also, the behavior is fully specified on all machines.)

Comment: Yep. But signature is a bit different.

Comment: @SGrebenkin: I have fixed the signature. Now it corresponds to first message.

Comment: @Suman Vajjala: if you are satisfied with the solution, you can mark it with green sign.

Answer (score 3):

Like that:

```
struct A{
  int somedata_A;
  int somespecificimplementation_A(someclass *S1){
    if ((void*) &(S1->a) == this)
    {
      std::cout << "S1 is a pointer to myself" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it safe to assume, then, that "this" is actually referring to c1?

Comment: Not going to work, the address of the *instance* of `A` inside of `someclass` may not be the same as the address of the `someclass` instance that owns the instance of `A`.

Comment: @SGrebenkin No, it doesn't work in VS2010, except coincidentally in a few cases.  Try adding other members to `someclass`, before member `a`, or adding a virtual function to `someclass`.

Comment: One needs also take into account the field somedata_someclass, and make an appropriate shift. so, one should take and address of S1->a

Comment: Possibly worth stressing that this requires `S1->a` to be visible from within `struct A`.

Comment: Yep. Actually, the initial code is a bit wierd, since it's not C++. Moreover c1.a.somespecificimplementation_A(c2) won't work even if we add correct return values to the method declaration, since this call is private. Anyway, it is clear, what the auther wanted to say by this example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `struct A` has a pointer to `c1`, you can then take a pointer to `c2` and compare pointer values? Similar to what you would do with assignment operator overloads?

Comment: Is there any other way to do it assuming A does not store c1's pointer? The reason I am asking this is that A need not know c1's existence or as a matter of fact any other object.

Comment: See SGrebenkin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why go the way around and pass a pointer of your class to the nested struct which you then have to test, when you can instead give a reference to the parent by the parent during its construction?

```
class someclass
{
    public:
        struct a
        {
            void foo()
            {
                parent.doSomething();
            }

            private:
                friend someclass;
                a(someclass & parent)
                : parent(parent)
                {}
                someclass & parent;
        } a;

        someclass() : a(*this) {}

    private:
        void doSomething()
        {
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Although technically unspecified, the following will work on
most modern, general purpose machines:

```
void A::somespecificimplementation_A( someclass* S1 )
{
    char const* s = reinterpret_cast<char const*>( S1 );
    char const* t = reinterpret_cast<char const*>( this );
    if ( this >= s && this < s + sizeof( someclass ) ) {
        //  This A is a member of S1
    } else {
        //  This A isn't
    }
}
```

Having said that, I would stress:

1. This *is* not specified by the standard.  It will work on
   machines with a flat, linear addressing, but may fail (give
   false positives) on a machine with e.g. segmented memory.
2. I'd seriously question the design if `A` needs to know who it
   is a member of.
3. And if `A` really does need this information, it really should store
   a pointer to `someclass`, which is passed in to its constructor, so that the dependency is manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did understand the algo but why does it fail in the segmented memory case?

Comment: @SumanVajjala Because according to the standard, pointer comparisons for inequality are only valid between pointers into the same object; since on a segmented architecture, typically all pointers into the same object will have the same segment, an implementation can (and generally will) only compare the offsets.